# How to select an option field inside a table with Mechanize?

Tags: html, ruby, opencart, mechanize

I'm trying to select `<option value="20">Betaling ontvangen via Bank</option>` from the following html code (generated by OpenCart) with Mechanize:

```html
<div class="vtabs-content" id="tab-history" style="display: block;">
  <div id="history">
  <table class="form">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Bestelstatus:</td>

        <td><select name="order_status_id">
          <option value="23">Bestelling geannuleerd</option>

          <option value="17">Bestelling ontvangen</option>

          <option selected="selected" value="24">Bestelling verzonden</option>

          <option value="22">Betaling mislukt</option>

          <option value="20">Betaling ontvangen via Bank</option>

          <option value="19">Betaling ontvangen via PayPal</option>

          <option value="21">Betaling via Bank mislukt</option>

          <option value="18">Betaling via PayPal mislukt</option>

          <option value="25">Gereed voor afhalen (Delft)</option>

          <option value="26">Wachten op betaling</option>
        </select></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Mail naar klant:<span class="help">Wel zichtbaar voor klant bij
        de bestelinfo.</span></td>

        <td><input name="notify" type="checkbox" value="1"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Opmerkingen</td>

        <td>
          <textarea cols="40" name="comment" rows="8" style="width: 99%"></textarea>

          <div style="margin-top: 10px; text-align: right;">
            <a class="button" id="button-history" name=
            "button-history">Geschiedenis bijwerken</a>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

What I'm doing right now is:

```
puts single_order_page.field_with(:name => 'order_status_id').options[0].select
```

This prints out:

```
exampleshop.rb:44:in `block in <main>': undefined method `field_with' for #<Mechanize::Page:0x007f8ea514abf0> (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/narekaramjan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/mechanize-2.7.3/lib/mechanize.rb:442:in `get'
    from exampleshop.rb:7:in `<main>'
```

And `puts single_order_page` prints out the full HTML code of the page. You can take a look at the full code here: http://pastebin.com/pe5pjMzB.

`pp single_order_page` prints out this code: http://pastebin.com/ezSWWqi0

Any ideas?

#### UPDATE

POST request to update the order status:

```
$('#button-history').live('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=sale/order/history&token=545c8c415eb6641f29efc9e0b1180d2b&order_id=260',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: 'order_status_id=' + encodeURIComponent($('select[name=\'order_status_id\']').val()) + '&notify=' + encodeURIComponent($('input[name=\'notify\']').attr('checked') ? 1 : 0) + '&append=' + encodeURIComponent($('input[name=\'append\']').attr('checked') ? 1 : 0) + '&comment=' + encodeURIComponent($('textarea[name=\'comment\']').val()),
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('.success, .warning').remove();
            $('#button-history').attr('disabled', true);
            $('#history').prepend('<div class="attention"><img src="view/image/loading.gif" alt="" /> Even wachten a.u.b.</div>');
        },
        complete: function() {
            $('#button-history').attr('disabled', false);
            $('.attention').remove();
        },
        success: function(html) {
            $('#history').html(html);
            
            $('textarea[name=\'comment\']').val('');
            
            $('#order-status').html($('select[name=\'order_status_id\'] option:selected').text());
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like that:

```
page = single_order_page.parser

desired_element = page.search('//select[name="order_status_id"]/option[@value="20"]')
```

Then do whatever you want with it afterwards.

Comment: I want to select the option and click on a button to send a notification mail. I was using `puts` to check if I selected the correct option. Don't think the code would work in that case, or am I wrong?

Comment: If I understand you correct you would only need the value to send a request? The "right option" is the one matching "Betaling ontvangen via Bank"?

Comment: Is the value send via a GET or POST request? Can you copy the URL with the parameters in case of a GET request?

Comment: I found a piece of JavaScript code that sends the value via a POST request. Take a look at the updated question. The code is generated by OpenCart.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `field_with` is a `Form` method, not a `Page` method.

You want to do something like:

```
page = agent.get url
form = page.forms[0]
form['order_status_id'] = 20
next_page = form.submit
```